# JSON formatting is true in Global config and web.config file but I still i get error while POST method

Tags: xml, json

```
config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer= false;
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.UseDataContractJsonSerializer = true;
```

The error was:

> Error in the browser
>   This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

Comment: Looked all the way down to the page footer, couldn't see a document tree.

Comment: this is the document tree

Comment: <ArrayOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<string>value1</string>
<string>value2</string>
</ArrayOfString>